# How to run test functions with maven surfire plugin?

Tags: maven, kotlin, junit, pom.xml, maven-surefire-plugin

I want to run all tests in the test file, but Maven surefire plugin only recognizes tests if the name of the function within the test file has included "test". I am using junit for the @Test annotation.

How can I run all functions, without test in the functions name?

```
class TokenServiceTest {
@Test
fun testShouldNotRetrieveUserFromToken() {  //this one is running because there is test in the name
    setup()
    generateExpiredToken()
    val userName = tokenService.getUserFromToken(cookie?.value)
    assertThat(userName, IsNull.nullValue())
}

@Test
fun shouldHaveEntityIdentifier() { //this one isn't recognized by maven-surefire-plugin
    setup()
    generateTokenWithEntityIdentifier()
    val entityIdentifier = tokenService.getEntityIdentifierFromToken(cookie?.value)
    assertThat(entityIdentifier, Is.`is`("12345678"))
}
```

in my pom.xml

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>*Test</include>
                    <include>*TestCase</include>
                </includes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Which unit test framework do you use? I suppose you are using JUnit 4? Please show a full file including the imports etc..  Also why have you configured the default naming convention supplementally ... and why using such an old surefire-plugin version?

Comment: I am using spring. I am using 5.6.2 of Junit. imports are import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test . Updated my code

Comment: Please show the full code of the test and also your pom file... because I assume your doing something wrong... Spring or Spring boot?

Comment: spring boot. I tried also the highest version of surefire plugin, but still doesn't did the job.